# what could be the resulting mah if four 150 mah ,four 800mah and four 1000mah rechargeable cells all of the 12 cells in series to each other?

Tags: batteries, current, measurement, 12v, capacity

i wanted to know that what could be the resulting Mah if i connect four 150mah ,four  800 mah and four 1000 mah rechargeable cells all of the 12 cells in series to each other?all 1.2v

Comment: 0 mAh after some of those cells die quick deaths. Don't mix and match cells.

Comment: Please capitalise your questions properly to make them legible and to give a good impression. "Mah" should be "mAh", "V" for "volts", "I" for "i".

Comment: Abhishek Sharma - Hi, I have "rolled-back" (undone) your attempt to deface your own question to "delete it". That is not allowed - you cannot properly delete the question, as it has an upvoted answer, and defacing questions (or answers) isn't allowed either. Your only chance is to flag your own question for moderator attention, and ask them if they will delete the question for you - but they don't have to agree to do it.

Answer (score 4):

150mAh

After the lowest capacity batteries are discharged, the voltage will drop, and your device should shut down (but will probably keep running.)

If you keep using the device after the lowest capacity batteries are discharged, the batteries that still have charge will force current through the lower capacity batteries and destroy them - they will not reliably recharge, and may never recharge again.

Do not mix batteries with different capacities, and make sure that they are all equally charged.